# SQL Server 2016 select where in json array

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, sql-server-2016, json-query

I have a table [JsonTable], and the column [JsonData] save the json string,

JsonData like:

```
{
   "Names": ["John", "Joe", "Sam"]
}
```

How can I inner join this table like:

```
SELECT* FROM [TestTable] AS T
INNER JOIN [JsonTable] AS J ON T.[Name] IN JSON_QUERY(J.[JsonData], '$.Names')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function for reading `Names` array. You can use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM [TestTable] T
INNER JOIN [JsonTable] AS J ON T.[Name] IN (SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(J.[JsonData],'$.Names'))
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to use the cross apply operator like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [JsonTable] AS J
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.[JsonData], '$.Names') jsonValue
INNER JOIN [TestTable] T ON T.[Name] = jsonvalue.value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON_VALUE to get particular field value,

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TestTable] AS T 
INNER JOIN [JsonTable] AS J 
ON T.[Name] IN JSON_VALUE(J.[JsonData], '$.Names');
```

for the nested value have look this link : [JSON_VALUE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql)

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'JSON_VALUE'. Expecting '('.